# Creating new Excel workbook and copying specific tabs into it

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a new workbook, and then copy specific tabs over into it, however getting an 'Invalid Qualifier' error on compiling.

I don't know what the current workbook will be called, hence the need for code to define this

```
Sub NewWb()

Dim Aname As String
Dim Bname As String
Dim FileUse As String
Dim wbkCurrent As Workbook

Set wbkCurrent = ActiveWorkbook

Aname = "NewWorkbook_"
Bname = Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD")
FileUse = Aname & Bname

Debug.Print FileUse

Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileUse

wbkCurrent.Activate

wbkCurrent.Name.Worksheets(Array("Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3")).Copy Before:=FileUse.Worksheets(FileUse.Worksheets.Count)

End Sub
```

Comment: `wbkCurrent.Name.Worksheets…` is illegal syntax: just remove the `.Name` part. And `FileUse` is being declared as a `String` while you use it as a `Workbook` object: you may want to use `Workbooks(FileUse)...` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning a variable to the new workbook when you add it, and then you can reference it later in your code and avoid the need to activate things.

```
Sub NewWb()

Dim Aname As String
Dim Bname As String
Dim FileUse As String
Dim wbkCurrent As Workbook
Dim wbNew As Workbook

Set wbkCurrent = ActiveWorkbook

Aname = "NewWorkbook_"
Bname = Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD")
FileUse = Aname & Bname

Debug.Print FileUse

Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
wbNew.SaveAs Filename:=FileUse

wbkCurrent.Worksheets(Array("Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3")).Copy Before:=wbNew.Worksheets(wbNew.Worksheets.Count)

End Sub
```